# How to set up a smudge and clean filter so that it references a script tracked by the repository

Tags: git, git-filter

I have a project that uses Jupyter Notebook files for data analysis and I keep output and certain pieces of metadata out of git with a clean/smudge filter. I will sometimes make adjustments to the filter and I want to have these changes automatically applied instead of having to ask my collaborators to run a `git config` command each time.

How can I configure the filter to run scripts that are tracked by the repository?

For the purpose of this question, let's suppose the clean command is the one from [How to clear Jupyter Notebook's output and metadata when using git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73218382/21891079):

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR
```

This is typically configured as...

```bash
git config filter.<filter-name>.clean "<command>"
```

...and used with a `.gitattributes` that includes the following.

```
*.ipynb filter=<filter-name>
```

#### Related questions

- [.gitattributes smudge and clean filters as a part of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26125573/21891079) is close but related to setting up filters on `git clone` instead of tracking changes in the filter with the repository
- [How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155355/21891079) is a more general question about tracking any configuration file in a repository, not addressing the specifics of this qeustion.
- [What are the security risks with allowing smudge and clean filters to be configured with git clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77736457/21891079) is about setting up a filter on `git clone`, not about setting up a filter *after* cloning that uses a script in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up a smudge or clean filter in Git that references a script tracked by the repository, you need to use a relative path to the script in the repository from the project's root directory (actually, relative to your [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_filter), where the filter is declared)

```bash
+--------------------+
| Git Repository     |
|                    |
| +----------------+ |
| | .git           | |
| +----------------+ |
| +----------------+ |
| | Scripts        | |
| | +------------+ | |
| | | clean.sh   | | | <--- The script for the clean filter
| | +------------+ | |
| +----------------+ |
| +----------------+ |
| | .gitattributes | | <--- Specifies the filter for .ipynb files
| +----------------+ |
+--------------------+
```

For your specific scenario with Jupyter Notebook files, you can set up the clean filter by placing the clean script in your repository, e.g., `scripts/clean_jupyter.sh`. That script (which should be executable: `chmod +x scripts/clean_jupyter.sh`) will include the command you mentioned:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
jupyter nbconvert --ClearOutputPreprocessor.enabled=True --ClearMetadataPreprocessor.enabled=True --to=notebook --stdin --stdout --log-level=ERROR
```

Configure your `.gitattributes` file to use this script for your Jupyter Notebook files:

```bash
echo "*.ipynb filter=jupyterClean" >> .gitattributes

# result in your .gitattributes:
*.ipynb filter=jupyterClean
```

Set up the clean filter in `.git/config` to reference your script:

```bash
git config filter.jupyterClean.clean "scripts/clean_jupyter.sh"
```

To have these changes automatically applied to all collaborators, you can include instructions in your project's `README.md`, or set up an initialization script that they can run once to configure their local repository settings. Git does not allow the automatic application of filter configurations from a repository for security reasons, so manual setup is necessary.

---

To answer [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154948/how-can-i-track-system-specific-config-files-in-a-repo-project/2155355#comment137046585_2155355) on my old answer about "[How can I track system-specific config files in a repo/project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2155355/6309)":

> You say "That way, the script (managed with Git) referenced by the smudge". How exactly do you reference a script managed by git in the smudge filter? I'm relatively new to scripting and git filters but I would really like to get this working in my project.

The `smudge` or `clean` filter is a script which is:

- either relative to your .gitattributes file (where the filter is declared), as seen in [this example in `git/git/t/chainlint/token-pasting.test`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e79552d19784ee7f4bbce278fe25f93fbda196fa/t/chainlint/token-pasting.test#L2-L3)
- or a script in the `%PATH%` or `$PATH` of your shell session, in which case you can reference it by its name only (no path).